# What is the correct way to write the not operator preceding the evaluation?

Tags: c#

The following example is clear - we evaluate the bool prior to the ! check.

```
bool test = a==b;
if(test) do somehting
if(!test) do something
```

Suppose I want to combine the `!` check and evaluation then `if(!a==b)` will result in comparison of `!a` with `b`.

What is the correct way to write the not operator preceding the evaluation?

The following gives error:

```
if !(a==b)
```

Comment: `(!(a==b))` or `(a!=b)`

Comment: `if (a != b)` or `if (!(a == b))`

Comment: Are you looking for this: `if (a != b)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What is the correct way to write the not operator preceding the evaluation?**

> you can try if(!(a==b))

- But it looks complex and difficult to read, **elegant** way is to check `if(a!=b)`

**Why I say elegent?**

- `!(a==b)` and `a!= b` doing the same thing, but if you want to read the condition then it will come as

> `!(a==b)` : not `a` equal to `b`
>
> `a != b` : `a` is not equal to `b`

---

*Suppose I want to combine the `!` check and evaluation then `if(!a==b)` will result in comparison of !a with b.*. **Why?**

- If you look at [operator precedence table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), it says [`!x`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-) is **higher** precendence than [`x == y`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#equality-operator-).
- This is the reason your `if(!a==b)` interpreting `!a` as first and then `!a` is comparing with `b`.

---

**Note:**

If you have multiple conditions in `if` condition and you want to check the negation then it is **better** to use

```
if(!(condition1 && condition2 && conditionN))
```

instead of

```
if(!condition1 || !condition2 || !conditionN)
```

**Why?**

- As @TimSchmelter said, if you have multiple conditions then use of single `!` to turn the condition to negation, help us to make our code more readable and maintainable

Comment: " it looks complex and difficult to read" That's true for this case with only one comparison. If you have multiple it's often more readable and maintainable to use `if(!(cond1 && cond2 && cond3))` than to write `if(!cond1 || !cond2 || !cond3)`. Those comparisons can be hard to understand and then you have to negate them and understand the `||` correctly. You can simplify with a single negation.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I am completely agree with you. I updated my answer and included explanation for multiple conditions

Comment: What about presence of await keyword, then do we write `if (!await UserExists..)` or `if (await !UserExists)` ?

Comment: @variable, I personally never tried negation with `async..await` method. I tried it on fiddle and it works like `if(!await UserExists)` https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3Q8fX. BTW apologies for late response

Answer (score 0):

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence for the operator precedence list in C#. The ! operator has a higher priority than the == operator, so `if (!a == b)` evaluates as `if ((!a) == b)` which is obviously not the same as `if (!(a == b))`.